# Why does my on activity parameters give me Required ;

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am right now trying to send data from one activity to another and I now wonder why the int requestCode, int resultCode, gives me that the variables are never used plus why do they go red for that? it also gives me a reuired ; ? I am taking help of this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#13 and I can't see where he adds the request code? maybe you guys can find it... thx for the help before hand

```
package com.example.jenso.paperseller;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomerDatabase database;
    FloatingActionButton fab;
    private CustomerViewModel mCustomerViewModel;
    final int NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;



    private static final  String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        final PapperRecyclerAdapter adapter = new PapperRecyclerAdapter(this);


        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        mCustomerViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CustomerViewModel.class);

        mCustomerViewModel.getmAllCustomers().observe(this, new Observer<List<Customer>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Customer> customers) {
                adapter.setCustomer(customers);
            }
        });
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode; int resultCode; Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Customer customer = new Customer(data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.EXTRA_REPLY), data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.SECOND_REPLY),data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.THIRD_REPLY),data.getStringExtra(CreateCustomer.FOURTH_REPLY));
                mCustomerViewModel.insert(customer);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        R.string.empty_not_saved,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Do this when you click");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateCustomer.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);


            }

        });
















    }







}
```

Comment: By red, you mean red in the Android Studio editor? If it is that case put the mouse on top of the red line an it should give you a hint of what is going wrong.

Comment: `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode; int resultCode; Intent data)`  Change this line to `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`  Use commas to separate values in the method parameters

Comment: I have done that but It gives me identifier expected as a error code

Comment: when I'm holding over the red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have written onActivityResult method inside onCreate method, please write it outside the onCreate method. 
Hope this works..!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if you want to get some result from next activity you need to use `startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode );`

The **Request code** is basically the id of sender for example you may have two buttons that are calling two different activites to get result from them in this case if you use same requestCode you will not understand which activity is sending you data back. To distinguish between both you use different requestCodes.

Now in onActivityResult you first check the requestCode and then check ResultCode.

**ResultCode** is indicator whether the acitvity has provided you ok result or not.

Comment: I am doing this in my fab though should I add request code on top of the intent, NEW_CUSTOMER_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE

Comment: cuz I mean the only thing he is doing is startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: sorry i didn't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: if you take a look at my code I have This written in my fab button  startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) I wonder shouldn't the request code then be the NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE